# How to Return Json result

Tags: c#, json

Am getting the following Data as Output:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
{
  "Table1": [
    {
      "ID": "127",
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "ID": "128",
      "Name": "Test2"
    },
    {
      "ID": "129",
      "Name": "Test3"
    }
  ]
}
</string>
```

I tried to convert my dataset result in to Json result using below code:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset, Formatting.Indented);
```

This are my property code:

```
 public string GetiGPClientMaster()
        {
            using (var context = new TestData())
            {
                try
                {
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    IQueryable<ClientMaster> result = PersistSvr<ClientMaster>.GetAll(context).Where(i => i.Status == true);
                    List<WCFSource> listClient = result.Select(b => new WCFSource() { ID = b.ClientID, Name = b.ClientName }).ToList();
                    DataTable dt = ConvertToDatatablePayGroup(listClient);
                    dataset.Tables.Add(dt);

                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset, Formatting.Indented);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }`
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the location where you execute `GetiGPClientMaster` expects a `xml` formatted response rather than a Json response. Can you post the code where you call `GetiGPClientMaster` ?

Comment: If you have the function GetiGPClientMaster() in a MVC controller try to change the return value string to JsonResult

Comment: What type of project is this? is GetiGPClientMaster() a MVC method or ApiController method?

Comment: Hi Marcus, It is MVC Project and GetiGPClientMaster() is a ApiController